# Feferman-Vaught theorem and Term Powers

Tags: logic, model-theory

In an example of usage of [quantifier elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination) in wikipedia, it briefly mentions Feferman-Vaught theorem and Term Powers, but I am finding little information on what these are. Can anyone explain what Feferman-Vaught theorem and Term Powers are?

Answer (score 1):

There's a section on the Feferman-Vaught theorem on page 458 of Hodges' "Model Theory" :)